# What is the minimum energy required to move heat from cold to hot side?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the minimum energy required to move a unit of heat from the cold side of a system to the hot side?

One obvious lower bound is that it must be at least as much as the amount of work that can be done by a maximum efficiency heat engine when that heat moves back. So for example, for a system with the cold end at 0°C and the hot end at 50°C (323K), maximum heat engine efficiency is 50/323 = ~15%. By this logic, since 1J of heat moving from hot to cold side can perform at most 0.15J of work, therefore it must take *at least* 0.15J of energy to move 1J of heat back from the cold end to the hot end at these given temperatures. Assuming I made no mistakes here.

Is this the actual theoretical lower bound on the energy required, or is there a higher theoretical lower bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By this logic, since 1J of heat moving from hot to cold side can
> perform at most 0.15J of work, therefore it must take at least 0.15J
> of energy to move 1J of heat back from the cold end to the hot end at
> these given temperatures. Assuming I made no mistakes here.

That is correct, because then you are talking about a heat pump, i.e., a heat engine operated in reverse.

The minimum amount of energy (work) needed to move a unit of heat from a cold environment to a warm environment is determined by the maximum possible coefficient of performance (COP) of the heat pump, which is the Carnot COP.

For any heat pump,

$$COP=\frac{Q_H}{W}$$

The maximum possible COP for a heat pump is the Carnot COP

$$COP=\frac{T_H}{(T_{H}-T_L)}$$

So if $T_{L}$=273 K (0 C), and $T_{H}$ = 323 K (50 C), $COP_{max}$ = 6.46

Substituting into the first equation,

$$W=\frac{Q_H}{6.46}$$

So if $Q_H$ = 1J, the minimum work required is $W=0.155 J$, which is what you calculated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the lower bound arises from the impossibility of destroying entropy, which is forbidden by the Second Law. If you wish to move $Q/T=1\,\mathrm{J}/273\,\mathrm{K}$ of entropy into the hot end, you can remove no more than $0.845(=273/323)\,\mathrm{J}$ from the cold end, or you'll end up with excess entropy. The energy remainder of $1-0.845=0.155\,\mathrm{J}$ must then come from reversible work you do on the system.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks for providing your additional insight. OP take note.

Comment: That is indeed a very interesting additional insight. Thanks both!